# SIP - How to implement functions like Buddy-Search or Buddylist-Modification

Tags: sip

i'm currently working on a project where i have to develope a communication-system for sip. The system consists of UserAgents and a central SystemServer (basis: mobicents), which contains all user-information and where UserAgents can register themself. As known from systems like skype or icq, my UserAgents have also a BuddyList (stores the sip-uri and name of an other user).

Buddy-Search:
To add a new user to the buddylist, I want to implement a search function on the server. But I have no idea which SIP-Message to use. On my inet-search I've read some vague ideas about implementing this with an single Subscribe-Message to the server (e.g. Event: buddysearch, Body: searchparams --> 200-Response with Searchresults). Is this the right choice to implement such a function?

Buddylist-Modification:
Another function of my SystemServer is, that UserAgents can subscribe for presence-information about their buddies. That means the Server notifies them about status-changes of their buddies (like online, offline). Therefore the Server must always have the current buddylist-data. How should I notify my server about changes (e.g. removed user from buddylist)? Maybe with standalone notifies? (a previous subscription on the UA by the server makes no sense in my eyes)

As you can see I'm a bit unconfident about how to implement this functions correctly. I hope you can help me there, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track with `SUBSCRIBE` and `NOTIFY` for you project.

Before going your own way, take a look at [SIMPLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMPLE).

Comment: Thx, for your answer. I'll have a look at simple ;)